# Delete login IP Restrictions in profile doesn't persist

Tags: metadata-api, profile, login

Removing all login IP restrictions on a profile in the sandbox via Metadata (removing all the login IP sections in the XML) and saving the file, but the change isn't reflected in the org.

The docs at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm state (with my emphasis)

> To delete **login hour restrictions** from a profile that previously had them, you must explicitly include an empty loginHours tag without any start or end times.

Could the same be true of **login IP restrictions** as well?  The doc doesn't *explicitly* say so, but it would largely make sense that it worked in a consistent way

Comment: API version 39.0 according to MavensMate settings

Comment: From my testing, appears impossible. I thought there was a version or way to do so, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transposing @sfdcfox comments into an answer, so I can mark it as accepted answer

> From my testing, appears impossible. I thought there was a version or way to do so, but I can't find it. – sfdcfox May 10 at 14:35